# Reading from files from SFTP with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I want to periodically read csv files from an SFTP server (just user and password) and add each line as a json message to a topic in my message broker (in the case its GCPs Pub Sub), without the need to copy the file.
I read through https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/sftp/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp, but it doesn't seem to have the capability to do what I described above. 
How can that be accomplished?

Comment: First, you are using the wrong (outdated) starters. So here is where you should be looking at - https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/sftp. With regard to ". . .but it doesn't seem to be able to send those messages to a specific channel nor to parse each line to format it. . ." - it means absolutely nothing. Please include additional details in your question (e.g., stack trace, logs etc), otherwise it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I've made some changes to the question, hopefully it's better worded now